# How to stop URL Redirection on Browser?

Tags: laravel-5, server, cpanel

I am developing a website using laravel framework. And i wanted to remove `public` from the URL. To do so i redirected the url http://statustan.com to http://statustan.com/public in cPanel.

I removed the redirection after sometime still the site is getting redirected to the `public` folder.

I used SSH to edit the `.htaccess` inside the root directory and have deleted it but the issue persist.

When i opened the website on another PC it is working fine without redirecting. So i searched more and found that i have to flush the DNS so I tried the command `ipconfig /flushdns` and restarted the browser and PC still no luck.

How to fix this issue?

**Update**:

- I am using Mozilla Firefox Developers Edititon 60.0b10 (64-bit)
- I am not facing this issue on other browsers in my PC

Comment: can you try in incognito mode?

Comment: It is working fine on incognito mode

Comment: the page uses 301 permanent redirect and the browser cached

Comment: that worked....i clear the cache going through settings....buy why ctrl+f5 didn't work. It is supposed to refresh cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with caching. When I cleared the cache going through the settings of the browsers, it worked.